# saving arraylists to internal storage

Tags: arraylist

I am writing a program which calculates and shows Installed program's data usage.
I want to save My variables and reload them.
I have checked other questions about this but i didn't find my answer.
I have 5 Arraylists in my code to save these items:
"Application Name","Application Icon","Received Data","Sent Data" and "Total Data".
I get these informations and convert Arraylists to String arrays whith "for loop" and show them with my custom Adapter and a listview.
My problem is that my application force stops when i run it on my phone.
I save some variables with SharedPreferences and save Arraylists into internal storage.
I have also tried to save Arraylists with SharedPreferences and i could save them. but when i want to reload and set them to arraylists, i get error.
Here is my "onCreate" method code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private static final String MyPREFERENCES="MyPrefs";
private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
int first;
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> s=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> r=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> t=new ArrayList<>();
List<Drawable> ic=new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> StartRx=new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> StartTx=new ArrayList<>();
private long StartTotal;
private long TotalDataUsage;
private long prevData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainListView1);
    registerForContextMenu(listView1);

    myPrefs=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    first=myPrefs.getInt("FirstCall",0);
    StartTotal=myPrefs.getLong("StartData",0);
    TotalDataUsage=myPrefs.getLong("TotalData",0);
    prevData=myPrefs.getLong("prevData",0);
    try {
        list=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"NamesList");
        r=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"ReceivedData");
        s=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"SentData");
        t=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"TotalData");
        ic=(ArrayList<Drawable>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"IconsList");
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();***
    }
    DataUsage();
    int l=list.size();
    if (l>0) {
        String[] Names = new String[l];
        String[] DReceived = new String[l];
        String[] DSent = new String[l];
        String[] DTotal = new String[l];
        Drawable[] icons = new Drawable[l];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            Names[i] = list.get(i);
            DReceived[i] = r.get(i);
            DSent[i] = s.get(i);
            DTotal[i] = t.get(i);
            icons[i] = ic.get(i);
        }
        assert listView1 != null;
        listView1.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, Names, DReceived, DSent, DTotal, icons));
    }
}
```

and "onResume" method code is:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"NamesList",list);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"ReceivedData",r);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"SentData",s);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"TotalData",t);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"IconsList",ic);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = myPrefs.edit();
    edit.putInt("FirstCall", first);
    edit.putLong("TotalData",TotalDataUsage);
    edit.putLong("StartData", StartTotal);
    edit.putLong("prevData", prevData);
    edit.commit();
}
```

and the "InternalStorage" class is:

```
public final class InternalStorage {
private InternalStorage() {}
public static void writeObject(Context context,String fileName,Object object) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos=context.openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}
public static Object readObject(Context context,String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis=context.openFileInput(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    return ois.readObject();
}
```

}

I didn't get any error from android studio.

I know that the problem is with below codes because when i delete them, it works!

```
try {
        list=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"NamesList");
        r=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"ReceivedData");
        s=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"SentData");
        t=(ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"TotalData");
        ic=(ArrayList<Drawable>) InternalStorage.readObject(this,"IconsList");
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this code:

```
try {
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"NamesList",list);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"ReceivedData",r);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"SentData",s);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"TotalData",t);
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this,"IconsList",ic);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

CAN ANYONE HELP ME PLEASE?!!